# Ubuntu 14.04 KVM Host - Only network device pcnet working

Tags: ubuntu, networking, kvm-virtualization, virtio

I've installed a KVM host on Ubuntu 14.04. I've added a networking bridge as br0 and also added the p4p1 network adapter to it.

My problem is now that only the "pcnet" networking guest driver is working well. All the others "e1000", "ne2k_pci", "rtl8139" and "virtio" doens't work. With these drivers I have no network connection and also no PXE boot (Timeout).

But I want to use the virtio driver for performance reasons.

Installed packages: apt-get install qemu-system-x86 qemu-kvm virt-manager lvm2

My bridge configuration:

```
    #brctl show
    bridge name     bridge id           STP enabled      interfaces
    br0             8000.002590d4ef56   no               p4p1
                                                         vnet0
    virbr0          8000.000000000000   yes
```

The vnet0 interface was added by kvm automatically.

My /etc/networking/interfaces File looks like:

```
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

    auto br0
    iface br0 inet static
      address 5.101.XXX.XX
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      gateway 5.101.XXX.1
      bridge_ports p4p1
```

Maybe you guys have an good idea :)

Thank you very much.

Comment: You forgot to say what was the guest OS that you installed?

Comment: I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 on the guests but the IPXE boot also don't work. So I don't think its an guest problem. It must be something with the kvm host itself.